# Add/Change html styles onclick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started modifying my accordion function to change or add style to specific class elements and after various "versions" of this function, I asked AI and that also flipped me over with overcomplicated stuff that doesn't work.

Here is the code I have now:

```js
function toggleSnp(){
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  let snpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.snp');
  snpElement.addEventListener('click');
  if (snpElement.style.transform.scale === 'scale(3)') {
    snpElement.style.transform = '';
  }else{
    snpElement.style.transform = 'scale(3)'
  }
}
toggleSnp();
```

This is where I inspired of:

```js
let accordions;

function getAccordions() {
    accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("services");
    
    for (let i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
        accordions[i].addEventListener("click", Accordion);
    }
}
function Accordion() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let panel = this.getElementsByClassName("panel");
    let j;
    for (j = 0; j < panel.length; j++) {
        if (panel[j].style.maxHeight) {
            panel[j].style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            panel[j].style.maxHeight = panel[j].scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
};
getAccordions();
```

This is where I started from, I have 5 functions that make the same thing but for different elements and I want that simplified in on function using `querySelectorAll`:

```js
function toggleFive() {
  const snpElement = document.getElementById("five");

  if (snpElement) {
    const currentTransform = snpElement.style.transform;

    if (currentTransform === "scale(3)") {
      snpElement.style.transform = "";
      snpElement.style.position = "";
      snpElement.style.top = "";
      snpElement.style.margin = "";
      snpElement.style.zIndex = "";
    } else {
      snpElement.style.transform = "scale(3)";
      snpElement.style.zIndex = "9";
    }
  }
}
```

I want to simplify my process of changing one style to some HTML elements using only one function.

Comment: I would try posting a [mcve] of your HTML too.

Comment: `snpElement.addEventListener('click');` ? Nono. Not only there's a function missing, that's a collection of elements! JS is not jQuery, you need to explicitly forEach. Also don't *"go-get-styles"* in JS. Just toggleClass! To recap, set the *active* styles in CSS! And in JS just toggle that *active* class. That simple. The premise it to avoid `style` in JS.

Comment: Also calling `toggleSnp` by itself doesn't pass along `this` so that doesn't refer to anything.

Comment: In the Accordion example, the `this` keyword is used to refer to "the accordion thing that was clicked".  You can also use `this` to refer to the snpElement that was clicked, ie `const snpElement = this` - no need to have separate functions for each element.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply make more than one CSS class and toggle between them

Comment: No. You don't need to toggle between two classes. Think like a developer. You need to only toggle one class. You need a default state styles and toggle one *active* class that overrides the defaults.

Comment: thinking like a developer it is always about finding the easiest solution and it's CSS, js this not affect the website performance

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).